# Prevent AdView from being pushed up screen by keyboard

Tags: android, scroll, admob, android-softkeyboard

This is a simple representation of my activity:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- my adview is here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- some stuff -->

    <EditText>
        <!-- multiline EditText -->
    </EditText>

    <!-- some other stuff -->

</LinearLayout>
```

When the EditText gets focus the keyboard comes up and I start typing.
If I press enter a few times, the EditText is then being resized (gets bigger since it's a multiline edittext) and the upper edge of the EditText shiftes upwards by pushing my adview up out of the screen.

I'm using the Google Play Services Mobile Ads.

Is there a way to keep the adview in the screen? I don't care if the content of the EditText is "scrolled" out of the screen. I want the user to be proposed the ad all the time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set either *maxHeight* or *maxLines* for your EditText to limit it's vertical height.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Also configure the EditText to only take as much room as required but to grow if possible.
Eg

```
<EditText
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

This should cause the EditText to collapse when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: Actually the EditText takes up all the free place that remains on the screen.